# Is there a way to insert holidays into all users' Outlook calendars?

Tags: exchange-2007, automation, outlook-2007, outlook-2003

Does anyone know of a way to insert holidays from a .hol file into the Outlook calendars of all our users?

I know that Outlook has holidays for all countries which just need to be manually added by the user. In South Africa, holidays which fall on a Sunday cause the following Monday to be a holiday as well, which Outlook's standard holiday list does not take into account.

We have a custom .hol file which adds these bonus Monday holidays, but I can't find a way to add these to the calendars for all users without user intervention.

The command line option `outlook.exe /hol <file.hol>` is the closest I've come to a solution, but it still requires user confirmation.

Clients are using Outlook 2003/2007 and the server is Exchange 2007.

Edit: To clarify, this needs to be done in the user's security context, via a login script or similar. I cannot do this server-side due to mailbox permissions which cannot be changed for non-technical reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a pst file containing the holidays events, and import it into mailboxes using the **Import-Mailbox** cmdlet.

[This article](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Adding-Events-Multiple-Mailboxes-Exmerge.html) has informations on doing this using Exmerge and provide a VBScript to duplicate the PST with the correct mailbox.nickname for the import step.

Next for the import phase you may have a look at [this article](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/04/13/437745.aspx) on the MSExchangeTeam Blog
regarding the cmdlet replacing Exmerge in Exchange 2007.

Hope this fits your needs.

Comment: I probably won't be able to do that because Import-Mailbox will require me to alter mailbox permissions. Last time I tried to get approval for this, even temporarily, the answer was a very non-negotiable "no". If nothing better comes along in the next day or so I'll accept your answer since it fulfils the technical requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it should be reasonable feature in Exchange. I'm trying to do something similar, and it looks like the only options are 3rd party options.